# How do I know when to use parenthesis when chaining datetime functions in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, parentheses

I am learning Python and was hoping someone here can help clear something up for me.

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

ser = pd.Series(['01-01-2010', '02-02-2011', '03-03-2012', '04-04-2013'])
ser_ts = pd.to_datetime(ser)

ser_ts_daynum = ser_ts.dt.weekday.tolist()
ser_ts_dayname = ser_ts.dt.day_name().tolist()

print(ser_ts_daynum)
print(ser_ts_dayname)
```

Why do I need parenthesis in `day_name()` when defining `ser_ts_dayname`, but not for `weekday` within `ser_ts_daynum`? I get an error if I try the opposite.

I feel like I'm missing something about how to chain functions in Python. I'm very familiar with piping in R (`%>%`) but things don't seem to work the same way in Python. Greatly appreciate any insight!

Comment: Did the docs not answer this? You can specify optional arguments to the [`day_name()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html) *function* in the parentheses. [weekday](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday.html), on the other hand, is a *property*.

Comment: There is no rule that can be easily used to determine whether something is a function or a property in the library. This is largely a design decision and it is best to consult the docs when determining how to use a given function.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way of knowing. Here are a few pointers to try to determine what to do:

### 1. Check the documentation

[`pandas.Series.dt.day_name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html) gives a use case, with parentheses, while [`pandas.Series.dt.weekday`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.weekday.html) is without parentheses.

### 2. Check the type

Methods needs parentheses to be executed

```
>>> type(ser_ts.dt.day_name)
method
```

This is more tricky to identify properties (which do not need parentheses) as the type of the linked object will be returned:

```
>>> type(ser_ts.dt.weekday)
pandas.core.series.Series
```

### 3. Check the signature/docstring (interactive interpreter)

When using ipython/jupyter or any interactive interpreter, you can add a `?` at the end of the name (without parentheses)

If a property, this is a reference to a inner object, you do not need parentheses.

```
>>> ser_ts.dt.weekday?
Type:        property
String form: <property object at 0x7fd0234d3770>
Docstring:  
The day of the week with Monday=0, Sunday=6.
...
```

else, you have a signature, this is a method, you need parentheses.

```
>>> ser_ts.dt.day_name?
Signature: ser_ts.dt.day_name(*args, **kwargs)
Docstring:
Return the day names of the DateTimeIndex with specified locale.
...
```

### 4. Give parentheses a try ;)

```
>>> ser_ts.dt.weekday()
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

OK, looks like you did not need it